# Kotlin uri.getQueryParameter not working with hashroute

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android kotlin code I want to get the value of a query parameter and when the uri string is like below

```
example.com/sharelink?id=123
```

then `url.getQueryParameter('id')` returns the correct value.

but if the uri is in hashroute format like below

```
example.com/#/sharelink?id=123
```

then `url.getQueryParameter('id')` returns null.

Here the uri is not in my control so I cannot change this hashroute format.

Could anyone please help me to resolve the query parameter in a proper way rather than using any string matching.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it just replace `#` in the URL and then parse it. Other way you can use `uri.fragment` to get the part of request and then call `getQueryParameter` on it.

```
val uri= Uri.parse("example.com/#/sharelink?id=123")
val id= Uri.parse(uri.fragment).getQueryParameter("id")
```

`uri.fragment` will return a `String` in this case `/sharelink?id=123`

I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Thanks. uri.fragment is the better way. UrlQuerySanitizer is also a solution by your answer is the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UrlQuerySanitizer`

```
import android.net.UrlQuerySanitizer

val sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer('example.com/#/sharelink?id=123')
val queryValue = sanitizer.getValue('id')
```